# It wants to join a community with the wrong account

Tags: bug, feature-request, accounts

I have a Stack Overflow account with years of reputation. Then I made a mistake. I joined Meta, and the math group, and a few other groups under the Stack Exchange umbrella, using a newer email address. I didn't realize that they wanted to link together. And I started another account on Stack Overflow using my work email address with my recent employer (accessed only from a different Google Chrome identity).

Things got mixed up. It now happens, not infrequently, that I will try to open a Stack Overflow window from my regular identity – not my former work identity – and this question pops up:
[image]

I'm here to complain that this question doesn't have enough answers offered to me. Cancel doesn't cancel; it keeps coming back to the same place. Agreeing to start a new account makes a real mess, it cuts me off from my years of reputation. No, we need a third option that says "Login to another account." That would really help.

Comment: You might want to replace this image, which shows your real email address.

Comment: "*It*" in the Title does(n't) mean *anything*, just saying...

Comment: It isn't clear what "It" refers to in the title. The system (the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange software)?